# Java Result 134 in Cooja Simulator

Tags: java, jvm, simulation, cooja

I am getting crashes in Cooja, the Java is crashing with result 134 and the problematic frame is apparently "C  [libc.so.6+0x8fcdd]". Below is the log that is generated. Crash is happening after creating the nodes and when I start the simulation. I have tried to change the java version but it did not help. The log generated is below:

```
 [java] #
 [java] # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 [java] #
 [java] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f74658b0cdd, pid=31219, tid=31410
 [java] #
 [java] # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-3ubuntu3.18.10.1)
 [java] # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-3ubuntu3.18.10.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
 [java] # Problematic frame:
 [java] # C  [libc.so.6+0x8fcdd]
 [java] #
 [java] # Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/berk/Desktop/orchestra-thesis/tools/cooja/build/core.31219)
 [java] #
 [java] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 [java] # /home/berk/Desktop/orchestra-thesis/tools/cooja/build/hs_err_pid31219.log
 [java] #
 [java] # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 [java] #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 [java] # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 [java] # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
 [java] #
 [java] Java Result: 134
```

Comment: Please install `libc6-dbg` and try to obtain an annotated backtrace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have installed libc6-dbg but I am still getting the same error. Maybe do you have any other thought on that?

Comment: Can you generate a coredump and see GDB can generate complete backtraces? You can try to reproduce on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL, which has proper unwind tables even without debuginfo packages.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates a memory corruption due to overwriting freed native memory.

I would review the use of native libraries, but it is possible only the authors of cooja can help you fix this.

Is there a newer/older version you can use?